angular signal transform is not working with input.required
If i declare with input.required({transform: this.transformMe}) then i am getting
Type '(value: any) => any' is not assignable to type 'undefined'.(2322)
But If i declare with input({}, {transform: this.transformMe}) then it is working fine.
Also how to provide alias in input.required()
Playground-Link

Below is the type definition for input.required
required: {
    /** Declares a required input of type `T`. */
    <T>(opts?: InputOptionsWithoutTransform<T>): InputSignal<T>;
    /**
     * Declares a required input of type `T` with a transform function.
     *
     * The input accepts values of type `TransformT` and the given
     * transform function will transform the value to type `T`.
     */
    <T, TransformT>(opts: InputOptionsWithTransform<T, TransformT>): InputSignalWithTransform<T, TransformT>;
};

If you notice, we are getting first type InputOptionsWithoutTransform being set because we have defined only a single type for <T> ({ id?: number; title?: string }) which is causing it to use the first one, instead of we set, both <T, TransformT>(<InputRequiredCustomType, InputRequiredCustomType>) it will take the second type and transform will become available!
We can just add the property alias in the same place where we defined the transform and it works great!
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, booleanAttribute, input, output } from '@angular/core';

export type InputRequiredCustomType = { id?: number; title?: string }; // <- changed here
@Component({
  selector: 'app-each-post',
  standalone: true,
  template: `
      <h1>{{post()?.title}}</h1>
      <button (click)="onPost()">Action</button>
  `,
  imports: [CommonModule],
})
export class EachPostComponent {
  // where to add alias when using input.required
  post = input.required<InputRequiredCustomType, InputRequiredCustomType>({ // <- changed here
    alias: 'asdf',// <- changed here
    transform: this.transformMe,
  });
  // post = input({}, { transform: this.transformMe });
  onAction = output<{ id?: number; title?: string }>();

  transformMe(value: any) {
    return { ...value, title: 'my override title' };
  }

  onPost() {
    this.onAction.emit(this.post());
  }
}

Stackblitz Demo
